# Java 8: Why can't I parse this binary string into a long?

Tags: java, string, java-8, long-integer

Long story short, I was messing around with some basic genetic algorithm stuff in Java. I was using a `long` to store my genes, but I was using binary strings for readability while debugging. I came across an odd situation where I couldn't parse some binary strings that start with a `1` (I don't know if this is always the case, but it seems to be consistent with strings of 64 characters in length).

I was able to replicate this with the following example:

```
String binaryString = Long.toBinaryString(Long.MIN_VALUE);
long smallestLongPossibleInJava = Long.parseLong(binaryString, 2);
```

Which will throw and produce the following stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:592)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

Given that I have a correctly formatted binary string of sixty four characters in length, why can't I parse some strings to a long? Most of the time, my strings are randomly generated, but in the instance above this should work (seeing as `Long.MIN_VALUE` is definitely a valid long in Java).

Comment: If the first bit is a one then this denotes that the number is negative . So this is likely why you will struggle with strings starting with a 1, parseLong is signed and toBinaryString is unsigned.

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to go beyond 64 bits, [`java.util.BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) may come in handy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quoting [`Long.toBinaryString(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toBinaryString-long-) Javadoc (emphasis mine):

> Returns a string representation of the long argument as an **unsigned** integer in base 2.

And quoting [`Long.parseLong(s, radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-int-) (emphasis mine):

> Parses the string argument as a **signed** long in the radix specified by the second argument.

The problem comes from the fact that `toBinaryString` returns a unsigned value whereas `parseLong` expects a signed value.

You should use [`Long.parseUnsignedLong(s, radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseUnsignedLong-java.lang.String-int-) instead:

```
String binaryString = Long.toBinaryString(Long.MIN_VALUE);
long smallestLongPossibleInJava = Long.parseUnsignedLong(binaryString, 2);
```

Note that this is actually explicitely said in `toBinaryString` Javadoc:

> The value of the argument can be recovered from the returned string `s` by calling `Long.parseUnsignedLong(s, 2)`.